IntelliJ IDEA Spring Boot - How to disable "automatically detecting descriptor settings in application.properties"
It seems that with this feature on, Gradle won't generate a plain war for tomcat deployment; it will only generate a war executable using spring boot launcher which is not what I needed in this case.
Does anyone know how to disable this particular feature in IntelliJ or have any ideas on how to generate a deployable plain war file for tomcat with Gradle in IntelliJ?
